# Target an added element in jQuery while chaining?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

http://jsfiddle.net/Greg_J/R5ZHk/

I'm appending a div to a container and then animating the height. The height of div that is being selected is animating as you would expect it to.

What I want to do: I'd like to append the div, and then animate the appended div, all in the same chain.

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a slightly different (and arguably more readable) syntax that you can use:

```
$('<div>', {'class': 'inner'}).appendTo('#container').animate({ height: '25%'});
```

​
Also, the reason it isn't working is because you misspelled the `height` attribute in your CSS:

```
#container{
    width: 100px;
    heigh: 200px;
         ^
```

Here's a fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/R5ZHk/3/

Answer (score 2):

you could use find() with a selector to the object(s) and then keep on chaining... http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: @Greg-J, [it seems to work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/R5ZHk/4/) (Chromium 18/Ubuntu 11.04), mind you I did have to fix the typo on `heigh` to `height` first.

Answer (score 1):

.find() should work for you..

In the fiddle you made a typo for height

```
#container{
    width: 100px;
    heigh: 200px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .25);
}
```

Fix that and it should work all fine..